# Microsoft Azure threads per core

Tags: azure, central-processing-unit, vcpu

I am looking at the Pricing guide for Microsoft Azure.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/virtual-machines/windows/

How many threads are working in the "F16" "Compute Optimized" service they offer? It says 16 cores. But is it one thread per core or two threads?

From inside the VM the two CPUs are reported as being "Intel Xeon E5 v3 @ 2.40GHz", but I don't know if this is accurate outside the VM.

Comment: For Azure VM, a core that you get for these VM is a real logical core.

Comment: As in, not a physical core?

Comment: Yes, is a physical core.

Comment: Hi, `Threads` what do you mean?

Comment: Threads: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)

Comment: AFAIK some CPUs offer two threads per physical core, like the Intel Xeon E5. Others only offer one thread per core, such as the AMD processor on my personal computer. I don't understand what happens inside a VM however.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56966/discussion-between-walter-msft-and-posfan12).

Comment: I think the question being asked is do you get a core, which includes the facility to run two threads using hyperthreading, or do you get one of the threads that the core can support. I know on AWS you get the ability to run one thread, rather than a core that has two threads.

Comment: That is correct. At first I thought Azure falsely conflates threads with cores in the Pricing guide. I.e. the processor they use for F16 tier physically only has 8 cores, when they report 16 cores. But I forgot there are actually *two* processors per VM. E.g. 8 + 8 physical cores and 16 + 16 threads. So, I was just stupid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**On Azure, A Vm core gets for a physical core.**

F-Series VMs are based on the 2.4 GHz Intel Xeon® E5-2673 v3 (Haswell) processor, which can achieve clock speeds as high as 3.1 GHz with the Intel Turbo Boost Technology 2.0. More information please refer to this [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/f-series-vm-size/).

More information F-16 VM CPU refer to this [link](http://ark.intel.com/products/83356/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5-2630-v3-20M-Cache-2_40-GHz).

Comment: The F16 VM appears to use the Intel Xeon E5-2630 v3 listed here: http://ark.intel.com/products/83356/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5-2630-v3-20M-Cache-2_40-GHz

Comment: Also, each F-16 VM actually has two CPUs, not one. So I made a mistake.

Comment: Whilst this is still true, note that from the Dv3 series onwards Azure VM's will move to a virtual core model.

Comment: Does not answer the question as "hardware threads" are what the 2nd core is (Hyper-Threading is often referred to as hardware threads) and the question ONLY makes sense if "threads" means this.

Answer (score 2):

I hope you can help with the following,

**A – SERIES (A0 -A7)**

CPU: Intel Xeon®  E5-2630 v3 @ 2.4 GHz

Cores / Threads :  8 / 16, L3 Cache :  20 MB,  Data Width : 64 bit

**A – SERIES  (A8-A11)**

CPU: Intel Xeon® E5-2670 @ 2.6 GHz

Cores / Threads :  8 / 16, L3 Cache :  20 MB,  Data Width : 64 bit

**F- SERIES**

CPU : Intel Xeon® E5-2673 v3 (Haswell) @ 2.4 GHz   | 3.1 GHz with the Intel Turbo Boost Technology 2.0

Cores / Threads :  12 / 24, L3 Cache :  30 MB,  Data Width : 64 bit

**D – SERIES**

CPU: Intel Xeon® E5-2660 @ 2.20 GHz

Cores / Threads :  8 / 16, L3 Cache : 20 MB,  Data Width : 64 bit

**DV2 – SERIES**

CPU : Intel Xeon® E5-2673 v3 @ 2.40 GHz

Cores / Threads :  12 / 24, L3 Cache : 30 MB,  Data Width : 64 bit

**H – SERIES**

CPU: Intel Xeon® E5-2667 v3 @ 3.2 GHz

Cores / Threads :  8 / 16, L3 Cache : 20 MB,  Data Width : 64 bit

**G – SERIES**

CPU: Intel Xeon® E5-2698B v3 @ 2.00 GHz

Cores / Threads :  16 / 32, L3 Cache : 40 MB,  Data Width : 64 bit

[Source Link](https://cloudopszone.com/azure-vm-cpu-per-series/)